# Unable to figure out VGA [Verilog]

Tags: fpga, verilog, vga, spartan-6

After doing plenty of research on how to generate VGA signals and looking at a few code examples, I attempted to write my a simple VGA signal generator that just displays a single solid color on the screen.  When viewing the simulation, the timing appears to be correct.  When connected to a monitor, the monitor does not even acknowledge that a signal is being generated.  This has got me stumped, any help would be appreciated.

I am using timing information found here: http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing/640x480@60Hz

Sync pulse generator:

```
module VGASyncPulseGenerator(
    input clk, //50Mhz input clock
    input rst,
    output HS, VS, //Sync Pulses
    output active //High when active area is being drawn
);

localparam HS_START = 16; // hSync start (end of front porch)
localparam HS_END = 16 + 96; // hSync end (start of back porch)
localparam HA_START = 16 + 96 + 48; // end of back porch
localparam LINE = 800; // Length of entire line;

localparam VS_START = 480 + 10; // vSync start (end of front porch)
localparam VS_END = 6480 + 10 + 2; // vSync end (start of back porck)
localparam VA_START = 0;
localparam FRAME = 525; // Length of entire frame

reg [10:0] hPos = 0;
reg [10:0] vPos = 0;

reg pixelStrobe = 0;

assign HS = ~((hPos >= HS_START) & (hPos < HS_END));
assign VS = ~((vPos >= VS_START) & (vPos < VS_END));

assign active = (hPos >= HA_START) & (vPos >= VA_START);

always @(posedge clk) begin //generate pixel clock at 25MHz
    pixelStrobe = ~pixelStrobe;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (pixelStrobe) begin
        if (hPos == LINE) begin
            hPos <= 0;
            vPos <= vPos + 1;
        end else hPos <= hPos + 1;
        if (vPos == FRAME) vPos <= 0;
    end
end



endmodule
```

Top module:

```
module VGATest(
    input clk, rst,
    output HS, VS,
    output [4:0] B,
    output [5:0] R,
    output [4:0] G
);

wire active;

assign R = (active) ? 5'd1 : 5'b0;
assign G = (active) ? 4'd16 : 4'b0;
assign B = (active) ? 4'd1 : 4'b0;

VGASyncPulseGenerator pulseGen(clk, rst, HS, VS, active);
```

endmodule

Comment: People will want to know what hardware you're working on.  Some microcontrollers and such don't have stellar timing.  Monitor too in case the VGA standard it was built to is somehow relevant.

Comment: When designing and debugging firmware/RTL to interface with hardware, there are signals that have to have certain shape, level, and timing. It is customary to display the signals on oscilloscope, to make sure your code is doing right things. Which oscilloscope do you use, and can you post pictures of your RGB-sync traces?

Comment: It looks like LINE and FRAME loops are 1 too long. E.g. 0 to 800 is 801 cycles. I also think VS might be wrong, but a timing diagram from your simulation would help clarify.  Also for a physical implementation you need to register HS and VS otherwise they might have glitches.

Comment: You don't seem to have proper porches as you are using the same condition as a sync edge to mask the active region

Comment: I have been generating VGA data using FPGA board with a HDMI controller chip on it, and there was an initial handshake between the controller and the monitor via IIC interface. Maybe this is what you are missing?

Answer (score 3):

Problems I see in your code:

- 640x480@60 uses a pixel clock of 25.175 MHz, not 25 MHz. The difference may be enough to keep some monitors from synchronizing. Consider using a PLL to generate the appropriate clock (50 MHz x72÷143 gives 25.1748 MHz, which is within 9 ppm), or targeting 800x600@72 instead, which uses a pixel clock of exactly 50 MHz.
- The polarity of your sync pulses is wrong. 640x480@60 uses negative sync pulses -- `HS` and `VS` need to be low during sync, not high.
- There's a typo in the definition of `VS_END`. You probably want to use the constant 480, not 6480.

Possible problems outside your code:

- Do you have an appropriate constraints file? Are the signals being mapped to the right pins to reach the DAC?
- Make sure your levels are correct. R/G/B are 0 to 0.7V; sync voltages aren't critical but should probably be 3.3V.

Comment: I am using an Alinx AX516 board, and the constraints file was written based on provided documentation.  I changed the timing parameters to 800x600@72Hz, but the problem still persists.  I also fixed a mistake I found in the assignment of active.

Answer (score 0):

So after coming back to this, it would seem that the UCF file in my project was not being used for some reason.  This was the reason the module wasn't working.